# Is flexigrid really slow on IE6? What other alternatives can I use?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-6, performance, flexigrid

Is flexigrid (www.flexigrid.info) really slow on IE6?
Client wants me to support IE6, and does not want to use Firefox,
because most of their users are using IE6.
(NOTE: Flexigrid is much faster in Firefox)

What other alternatives can I use?

Regards,
Geff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was recommended to me [jgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) I haven't really looked at how slow either of these are in IE8 as my use of flexigrid has been internal and everyone here uses FF

HTH

Comment: I've also tried jqGrid, and it is still slow on IE6. I guess this is really a browser problem. :(

Comment: how many data are you trying to show at once and are you sure its the grid that's slow and not your server ?

Comment: Yes, the grid is slow. The server is fast. :) I need to show 100+ rows (at the minimum) with a max of 14 columns.

Comment: jqGrid is definitely faster than flexigrid. I wonder if there is still another library that is much faster than jqGrid.

Comment: I think flexigrid and jgrid are most likely the best out there